# how to filter by a shadow property and another property in the same SingleOrDefault() method in Entity Core 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have read the documentation about shadow properties in EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties

But I would like to filter by a shadow property and another property at the same time. I am trying this:

```
Proyecto? miProyecto = await _contexto.Proyectos
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => (EF.Property<long>(x, "IDCategoriaFactura") == 2)
                            && (x.NumeroProyecto = paramLgNumeroProyecto));
```

But I get an error when I add the second condition after the &&, that operation && can not be applied to operands of type bool and long?

How could I filter by the two properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of  `=` use boolean operator `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use equality operator instead of assignment one:

```
x.NumeroProyecto = paramLgNumeroProyecto
```

to

```
x.NumeroProyecto == paramLgNumeroProyecto
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía was glad to help! Happens even to the best of us.

Comment: A syntax error, so basic error. I didn't ralize. Thanks so much.